# Using CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, cors

In production I am posting to an ExpressJS server for payments with the Stripe API. For some reason, although I am using CORS and whitelisting the origin URL the post request is coming from, I keep getting the same error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

### Here is my `server.js` file in which I define cors:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const CORS_WHITELIST = require('./constants/frontend');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) =>
    (CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1)
      ? callback(null, true)
      : callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
};

const configureServer = app => {
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
};

module.exports = configureServer;
```

### The `index.js` file is where the configureServer function is used:

```
const express = require('express');

const SERVER_CONFIGS = require('./constants/server');

const configureServer = require('./server');
const configureRoutes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

configureServer(app);
configureRoutes(app);

app.listen(SERVER_CONFIGS.PORT, error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('Server running on port: ' + SERVER_CONFIGS.PORT);
});
```

### And here is the frontend.js file where the whitelist URLs are defined:

```
const FRONTEND_DEV_URLS = [ 'http://localhost:5000' ];

const FRONTEND_PROD_URLS = [
  'https://www.example.com',
  'https://example.com'
];

module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? FRONTEND_PROD_URLS
  : FRONTEND_DEV_URLS;
```

I can't seem to be able to debug the issue. Especially considering it only occurs in production.

Comment: Have you verified what `corsOptions` actually contains then?

Comment: Check your Network tab in the console to see whether the browser also issues an OPTIONS request (pre-flight request)

Comment: @haim770 Yes, there is a pre-flight request. It returns a status code of 204 (no content). In the request headers I see the origin as it is expected. EDIT: The value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin: in the pre-flight request response is exactly the same as the origin of the second request.

Comment: @MattHough, See https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight then

Comment: @haim770 But it is sending a pre-flight request and the origin supposedly being allowed is the same as the second request origin. Adding `app.options('/', cors())` didn't do anything.

Comment: @haim770 I have tried the complex method you suggested, switching to fetch(), switching to jQuery.ajax() and I am still getting the same error.